# Django Forms clean() method - need IP address of client

Tags: django, forms, ip-address

I am overriding the clean() method on a Django form. I want to have access to the IP address of the client (assuming this is a bound form). If I had a reference to the request object, I could get it easily from META("REMOTE_ADDR"). However, I do not have a reference to the request.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So give yourself a reference to it.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def clean(self):
        ip_address = self.request['META']['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

and in your view:

```
myform = MyModelForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

Comment: Why pop() it? Is that for cleanliness (like get rid of stuff you're not using)? Or, is it more efficient than get().

Comment: It's generally good practice. It's possible for example that the superclass method doesn't actually accept *args and **kwargs - it might only have named arguments in its definition. If so, passing the unexpected `request` argument will cause an exception.