# inserting a column on a django modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm writing a small survey app and the main model looks like this:

```
class survey(models.Model):
    ip_address = models.IPAddressField()
    question1 = models.IntegerField()
    question2 = models.IntegerField()
    question3 = models.IntegerField()
```

I also have a modelform that looks like this:

```
class countingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question1 = forms.ChoiceField()
    question2 = forms.ChoiceField()
    question3 = forms.ChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model=survey
        exclude=['ip_address']
```

I'd like to record the IP address of the person submitting each form, but I am unsure how to add this after the modelform comes back. As an example, this does not work:

```
form.cleaned_data['ip_address']=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
form.save()
```

I'd rather not add the IP address in as a hidden field. Suggestions?

Comment: On an unrelated note - your data model can potentially be incorrect, if a survey can ever have more than 3 questions. You might be better off having a `Question` model with a foreign key back to the survey.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Forms clean() method - need IP address of client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418611/django-forms-clean-method-need-ip-address-of-client)

Comment: found an answer here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form

Comment: Josh: About that Question model... I understand it from a data design point of view, but am unsure how to display something like that simply in the templates.

Comment: @jamida - your primary concern should be the data model! Otherwise you'll need to change it later, and it will be HARD. Ask another question, and we'll help you in that one.

Comment: @jamida, oh, I wouldn't set the IP address as it does in that documentation you found. Look at the duplicate link, it's a much better solution. It means your form logic is contained within the form. If you need to use the form elsewhere, the logic carries across.

Answer (score 3):

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
obj.ip_address = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
obj.save()
```

on the separate note, request may not have a REMOTE_ADDR field, so you should check your specific installation.